# Decomposing a set into a family of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with $\dim_\mathbb{C}(V)=n$. Consider now $V$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and let $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1},\dots,v_{2n}\}$ be a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$. I have stumbled upon the following question:

Show that one can partition $\mathcal{B}$ into two sets $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$, each of size $n$, such that $\mathcal{A}_i$, $i=1,2$, is a basis for $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try induction? If $n=1$, then $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1,v_2\}$, and of course both $v_1$ and $v_2$ span $\Bbb{C}$. Now assume it is true for all $V$ of dimension $n-1$. Can you prove it for $V$ of dimension $n$?